# JOIN two tables in MySQL and add values by row-ID

Tags: mysql, join

Given are two tables with with a common id and integer values:

```
table1:            table2:
| id   | val  |    | id   | val  |
+------+------+    +------+------+
| 1    |   0  |    | 1    |   1  |
| 2    |   1  |    | 1    |   1  |
| 3    |   1  |    |  2   |   2  |
| 4    |   2  |    |  2   |   2  |
| 5    |   2  |    |   3  |   2  |
                   |   3  |   2  |
                   |   3  |   2  |
                   |    4 |   6  |  <id shifted for readability>
```

How to archive this result in one query:

```
result-table:
| id   | val  |
+------+------+
| 1    |   2  |
| 2    |   5  |
| 3    |   7  |
| 4    |   8  |
| 5    |   2  |
```

**EDIT:**

Following some answers I got:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.val + SUM(t2.val) AS val
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id)
GROUP BY t1.id
```

what gives me:

```
id  val
1   2
2   5
3   7
4   8
5   NULL
```

But `2 plus nothing = 2` and not `NULL`. Is there a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `group by`:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.val - SUM(t2.val) AS val
FROM t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON (t1.id = t2.id)
GROUP BY t1.id
```

of course, I'm not sure why you're trying to subtract the values in your sample query. maybe you meant `+` instead?

Comment: Yes, I meant `+`. In my original use I need `-` but intended to change it to `+` in the question for a wider range of use. (i.e. more people might look for the sum)

Comment: Almost what I am looking for. But I am receiving a `val = NULL` for `id = 5`

Comment: This will give correct results only if the `id` is unique (or the primary key) in `table1`.

Comment: @simon: that's normal. if you don't want any `t1` rows where there's no matching values in `t2`, then use an inner join instead of a left join.

Answer (score 0):

use union instead of join:

```
     select id, sum(val)
     (
       SELECT t1.id, t1.val  as val 
       FROM table1 t1 
       union all # note this change to include all the value from 2 table  
       select t2.id, t2.val as val 
       from  table2 t2
      ) as unionTable
     groupby id;
```

Comment: well, union makes two table or more  as one table so you can make aggregate functions easily. Note that selected column must have the same order , count and datatype of column

Comment: I assume in your case you need sum all values in table 1 and table 2 group by id